# Unity 3d and RavenDB : System.InvalidOperationException: Could not convert document System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, database, unity-game-engine, ravendb

I am having some issues. I am not sure if it is with the data or with Raven. I am using Raven in Unity3d. I have been working for a week or two with support trying to get everything squared away, they even implemented some patches to make it work. I am really close now but keep running into the error of "System.InvalidOperationException: Could not convert document System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." The data in the DB currently is from a dump of the data from the 3.x version, so I am not sure if there were any differences in structure or anything that I have not taken into account but I used the built in importer and it took the data just fine and has not given any other errors or indication that it is an issue with that as far as I can tell.

I will try my best to explain and show some code, if anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. One issue I ran into at the start is I am using a game framework that was originally made a few years ago that I updated. It was using Raven 3.x, while trying to update it to 4.x is when issues were discovered with compatibility because Unity didn't implement .netstandard 2.0 yet. With the release last week of Unity 2018.1 RC1 comes support for .netstandard, so I was able to actually get communication between Unity and Raven finally.

Where it stands currently is the game attempts to query the DB to get NPC and item details to store in a cache.

Below is the original query from when it was using Raven 3.x (The line n => n.ZoneId == this.id is comparing the assigned ZoneId of the NPC to the ZoneId of the script that is calling the data. Nothing is actually referring to the Document ID that I have found)

```
        using (var session = this.world.WorldDatabase.OpenSession())
        {
            // load all npcs
            foreach (var npcData in session.Query<NpcData>("Npc/ByZoneId").Where(n => n.ZoneId == this.id))
            {
                var npc = new Npc(this, npcData.Guid, npcData.GroupId, (NpcType) npcData.NpcType, npcData);
                this.objectCache.AddItem(npc);

                var position = npcData.Position.ToVector();
                position.Y = this.GetHeight(position.X, position.Z);
                var rotation = Quaternion.CreateEular(0, npcData.Orientation, 0);
                this.PrimaryFiber.Enqueue(() => npc.Spawn(position, rotation));
            }
```

I wasn't sure if it didn't like that, so I tried to follow the documentations way of doing it as seen below.

```
                IList<NpcData> query = session 
                    .Query<NpcData>("Npc/ByZoneId")
                    .Where(n => n.ZoneId == zid)
                    .ToList(); 

                foreach (var npcData in query)
                {
                    var npc = new Npc(this, npcData.Guid, npcData.GroupId, (NpcType) npcData.NpcType, npcData);
                    this.objectCache.AddItem(npc);
                    var position = npcData.Position.ToVector();
                    position.Y = this.GetHeight(position.X, position.Z);
                    var rotation = Quaternion.CreateEular(0, npcData.Orientation, 0);
                    this.PrimaryFiber.Enqueue(() => npc.Spawn(position, rotation));
                }
```

I have a interface setup with this:

```
    IRavenQueryable<T> Query<T>(string indexName) where T : IDataObject;
```

and then a DatabaseFactory setup with this:

```
    public IRavenQueryable<T> Query<T>(string indexName) where T : IDataObject
    {
        using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<T>(indexName);
        }
    }
```

Here is what the data in the DB looks like, I figured an image would be a good idea so you can see the actual document name as well in case that helps with anything:

[https://i.imgur.com/Bb39WNm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EimKo.png)

No matter what I try though I keep getting back that error. If it helps, the full error is here below. If any more details are required, please do let me know and I will provide them.

Thanks in advance!

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not convert document NPC/1818637598 to entity of type Framework.Server.Data.NpcData ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
  at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) [0x00057] in :0 
  at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00013] in :0 
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x0000e] in :0 
  at System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00005] in :0 
  at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32 (System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider) [0x0011a] in :0 
  at Raven.Client.Json.BlittableJsonReader.ReadAsInt32 () [0x000c7] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndCreatorValues (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x000db] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ObjectConstructor`1[T] creator, System.String id) [0x000b2] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract objectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id, System.Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator) [0x0008b] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x00148] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0006d] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00053] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <dc86da7fc46c487ba6c7ab826da479cc>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Conventions.JsonNetBlittableEntitySerializer.EntityFromJsonStream (System.Type type, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject jsonObject) [0x0006e] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.EntityToBlittable.ConvertToEntity (System.Type entityType, System.String id, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject document) [0x0009b] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.EntityToBlittable.ConvertToEntity (System.Type entityType, System.String id, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject document) [0x000e1] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity (System.Type entityType, System.String id, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject document, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject metadata, System.Boolean noTracking) [0x000d0] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations.TrackEntity[T] (System.String id, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject document, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject metadata, System.Boolean noTracking) [0x00000] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.Operations.QueryOperation.Deserialize[T] (System.String id, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject document, Sparrow.Json.BlittableJsonReaderObject metadata, Raven.Client.Documents.Session.Tokens.FieldsToFetchToken fieldsToFetch, System.Boolean disableEntitiesTracking, Raven.Client.Documents.Session.InMemoryDocumentSessionOperations session) [0x0000d] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.Operations.QueryOperation.Complete[T] () [0x0007f] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.DocumentQuery`1[T].ExecuteQueryOperation (System.Nullable`1[T] take) [0x0005c] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Session.DocumentQuery`1[T].GetEnumerator () [0x00000] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Documents.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1[T].GetEnumerator () [0x00011] in <3af6f962c10f46e297126f8db0cace22>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) [0x00062] in <e1a80661d61443feb3dbdaac88eeb776>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00018] in <839a3cb835c04d14aeb58d83bb7bc4bd>:0 
  at Framework.Server.Game.MmoZone.LoadZone () [0x00215] in :0  Exception caught.

Comment: A very important note here. You are returning a Queryable object here from a session that you _disposed_. That is not a valid approach to take

Comment: I appreciate the reply. That was just one of several ways that I tried to do it. The current way I was trying is  seen here:

https://hastebin.com/ufuhalezuk.cs

but it has the same outcome, unfortunately of the error in the first post.

Comment: I tried starting with a new database as well, creating new collections, new entry, new index, etc to see if it made a difference because of my having imported data from a 3.x DB but unfortunately the outcome was the same error.

Comment: It looks like the issue ends up being I need to deserialize certain fields and convert the string to an enum byte. The string of text is technically correct, as its the name of the enum, but when it saved it, it just saved it to string.

Comment: Got it all worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it all worked out. It turns out because I was using enum/byte, RavenDB 4.x uses just string and numbers now so I had to add some extra json deserializtion / conversion methods to get data to load into my game, but its all working well now. Huge, huuuugeeee thanks to Oren of Raven for spending nearly a week working with me to get it all working though. He has the patience of a saint. I highly recommend this database!